# Import issue of header file of subproject

Tags: iphone, import, subproject

I created a subproject (`MySubproject`) in my main project(`TestProject`). In subproject I have 1 view controller (`subprojectviewcontroller.m`). I want to load this VC in my main project. But when I am writing `#import subprojectviewcontroller.h` in my `TestProject.m` file, it is saying an error header file not found.

*How will I import file of subproject in main project?*

Comment: why your are adding sub project rather than adding sub project you should use a view controller ..

Comment: @Abhishek It is a separate project. It is useful to handle 2 separate project.